# SQLite vs serializing to disk

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, serialization

I'm doing some performance comparison whether to go for serializing data or to store them in a a DB. The application receives hell of a lot of data (x GB) that needs to be persisted with a minimum speed rate of 18mb/s (as for now)

Storing in DB offers easier functionality in terms of searching and accessing data at a later time, data snapshots, data migration and etc, but my tests so far shows a huge difference in performance time.

The test saves 1000 objects (of about 7hundredsomething kb each). Either to their respective columns in table or to disk by saving them as a generic List. (The SQLite ends up with a bit more data)

1. Saving to SQLite v3, total size 745mb: 30.7seconds (~speed: 24,3 mb/s)
2. Serializing to disk, total size 741mb: 0.33 seconds (~speed: 2245 mb/s)

I haven't done any performance tweaks to SQLite, just use it out of the box with Fluent nHibernate and the SQLite.Data adapter (no transaction), but at first thought that is a huge difference.

Obviously I know that going through a ORM mapper and DB to write to disk gives an overhead compared to serializing, but that was a lot.

Also into considerations are to persist the data right away as I recieve them. If there is a power failure I need the last data recieved.

Any thoughts?

**----- Updates (as I continue to investigate solutions) ------**

- Wrapping the 1000 inserts in a transaction the time was now ~14s = 53mb/s, however if I throw an exception halfway I loose all my data.
- Using a IStatelessSession seems to improve the time by 0.5-1s
- Didn't see any performance gain by assigning the ID to the entity instead of having it automaticly assigned in the table and thus getting rid of (select row_generatedid()) for every insert sql. -> Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
- the nosync() alternative in SQLite is not an alternative as the DB might be corrupted in case of a power failure.

Comment: Did you try dapper with SQLite? http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ - Also, make sure you start a transaction on SQLite before you start inserting, if every insert runs in its own implicit transaction, you will kill performance outright.

Comment: as for the out-of-the-box solution it runs implicit yes. Not sure if I can run it differently though - the data needs to be persisted right away as it's fed to me and if I loose the whole result set waiting for the Commit during a power failure that would be bad. Will test it though.

Comment: @Islandwind: Consider using `INSERT OR [IGNORE]` then.

Comment: @AlixAxel not quite following you on that?

Comment: @Islandwind: The IGNORE option will cause the INSERT to not fail, even when it actually fails to insert - might be a good solution to use in conjunction with transactions, depending on your error handling strategy. Still, 14 seconds for 1000 INSERTs is still a crappy performance... Are you sure the bottleneck isn't the ORM?

Comment: @Islandwind: Also, have you tried benchmarking `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "table" VALUES (1, 'row-1'), (2, 'row-2'), (3, 'row-3'), ...;`?

Comment: @AlixAxel Not sure whether the ORM is the bottleneck. Thought nHibernate was quite good. I've been trying to tweak all possible settings in the framework with no much luck. I haven't tried IGNORE or multiple inserts as far as I know (played with some batch_size parameters..). Maybe will have to look into using something else yes.

Comment: I strongly recommend Alix's answer below. When you commit a modification to the DB, SQLite will `sync()` to disk — a _real_ transaction — and that takes usually two rotations of the physical disk. With typical disk speeds, that means you can only get a hundred or so transactions per second. Bunching the INSERTs into a single transaction (easy even with an ORM) will mean you pay the cost of `sync()` only once.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thanks for your views on this. If I understand AlixAxel right I can still have my data intact with an IGNORE, even if there is a power failure during the time I recieve data and persist them in transaction. I will look into bunching the INSERTS into a single transaction, but as the data is fed from a robot real time I can see some difficulties with that too. I might just look into persisting the heavy data to disk and save meta data to SQLite to get the performance needed.

Comment: If the chance of rejection is too high, it might be worth looking at why that is. For simple insertions of data where there's no constraints or triggers in the way, it ought to be possible to be able to just insert many times within a transaction. Deal with power glitches by fixing the power supply with a battery. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254563/preparing-sql-statements-with-pdo) once and I suggest you go the SQLite route.

As for your performance issues, I'm pretty sure you'll get a very significant boost if you:

1. execute all INSERTs in a single transaction - write queries must acquire (and release) a lock to the SQLite file, this is very expensive in terms of disk I/O and you should notice a [huge boost](http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html)***
2. consider using multi-INSERTs (this probably won't work for you since you rely on a ORM)
3. as @user896756 mentioned you should also prepare your statements

---

### Test 1: 1000 INSERTs

```
CREATE TABLE t1(a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,13153,'thirteen thousand one hundred fifty three');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2,75560,'seventy five thousand five hundred sixty');
... 995 lines omitted
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(998,66289,'sixty six thousand two hundred eighty nine');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(999,24322,'twenty four thousand three hundred twenty two');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1000,94142,'ninety four thousand one hundred forty two');
```

- PostgreSQL:     4.373
- MySQL:      0.114
- SQLite 2.7.6:       **13.061**
- SQLite 2.7.6 (nosync):      **0.223**

---

### Test 2: 25000 INSERTs in a transaction

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE t2(a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,59672,'fifty nine thousand six hundred seventy two');
... 24997 lines omitted
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(24999,89569,'eighty nine thousand five hundred sixty nine');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(25000,94666,'ninety four thousand six hundred sixty six');
COMMIT;
```

- PostgreSQL:     4.900
- MySQL:      2.184
- SQLite 2.7.6:       **0.914**
- SQLite 2.7.6 (nosync):      **0.757**

---

*** These benchmarks are for SQLite 2, [SQLite 3 should be even faster](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SpeedComparison).

Comment: +1: What's more, even bunching the INSERTs into groups of 10 or 20 will get good speedup.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using compiled statements for sqlite.

Check [this](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)

On insert/update queries there is a huge performance boost, I managed to obtain from 2x to 10x faster execution time using compiled statements, although from 33 sec to 0.3 sec is long way.

On the other hand, the SQLite execution speed depends on the schema of the table you are using, ex: if you have an index on a huge data, it would result a slow insert.

Comment: thanks for you link. I will check it out. The table is created from the domain model before the test is run (using Fluent nHibernate BuildSchema()) and as far as I know no index is created.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating further, the answer lays in a bit of a confusion of the intial results.

While testing the result with larger data I got some other result.

The disk transfer rate is limited to 126mb/s by the manufacturer and how could I write 750MB in a split second? Not sure why. But when I increased the data amount the transfer rate when fast down to ~136 mb/s.

As for database, using a transaction I got speeds up to 90mb/s using the IStatelessSession with large amounts of data (5-10GB). This is good enough for our purpose and I'm sure it can still be tweaked with compiled SQL statements and other if needed.